# hazelcast AtomicInteger increment is not updating

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm trying to implement a simple counter using hazelcast's map. I initialized a map like the following

```
HazelcastInstance hz = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();
IMap<Long, AtomicInteger> map = hz.getMap("my-distributed-map");
map.putIfAbsent(testKey, new AtomicInteger(0));
```

When I try to increment the counter (AtomicInteger), the map doesn't seem to update at all (not even locally).

```
map.get(testKey).incrementAndGet();
```

Printing the items in the map still shows the `testKey` to be 0, as supposed to the incremented value. Is this the expected case, and what may be the best way to implement a counter moving forward?

Edit:
This example works well with a typical java concurrentHashMap

```
private final ConcurrentMap<Long, AtomicInteger> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

And it does seems the hazelcast map is similar under the hood

> Hazelcast Map (IMap) extends the interface java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap and hence java.util.Map. It is the distributed implementation of Java map. You can perform operations like reading and writing from/to a Hazelcast map with the well known get and put methods.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way. You have to call:

```
Map.put(key, value);
AtomicInteger counter = map.get(testKey).incrementAndGet();
map.put(key, counter);
```

The change in object will not reflect in member/server instance (it is not local reference it is distributed object).

Comment: but `incrementAndGet()` returns a value of typ int, this doesnt work for me